# Receive-Job continuing with errors

Tags: powershell

I've got a Start-Job, Wait-Job, Receive-Job script to run for the purpose of ensuring a timeout isn't reached for a particular script. This is fine, it works but the problem is that when that script throws errors I'd like the script to continue to the end.

This, again, I can do with the " -ErrorAction Continue" flag on the Receive-Job call BUT then there response from the script is peppered with the below statements:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm ERR! instal...ad dependencies 
Error    09:46:50
   :String) [], RemoteException
Error    09:46:50
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
Error    09:46:50
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

And

```
NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException
```

Is there anyway to have the script execute as-is, without the Receive-Job writing anything additional to the output?

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop the job from generating error output, but you can route it to $null when you do the `Receive-Job`.

```
Receive-Job Job2 2>$null
```

Comment: I still want to capture the error output, I just don't want the additional info mentioned above that isn't included when run directly through standard powershell

Comment: They'll still be in $Error.  They just won't be written to the console.

Comment: You are completely correct. However, I want all the output together so I've combined to *>&1. The new problem is line breaks. The command is below which has a heap of linebreak output but I can't find the character that is causing the line breaks (not \r or \n or \t or \0)... Command "$output = npm install --production *>&1". $output has a heap of breaks in it

Answer (score 0):

Would have to see the script I guess. Could you not catch the part that's throwing the exception in a try..catch?

Comment: The script itself isn't throwing any exceptions. Some of the commands write to the error output, which powershell background tasks automatically throws exceptions for (which I don't want)

Comment: Man this sucks. Did you ever find a way to detect that no error was thrown but only stderr output?? @johnnyboy